# How to secure MongoDB connection string on GitHub?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got a project where I'm tasked with connecting the back-end of an APP to a database stored on MongoDB and using only Node. The front-end part was already made and not to be touched.

In my `App.js` file, I've got the connection string from MongoDb that is written in the following way:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

As you can see, the username and passwords are typed in clear, I want to secure those datas and maintain accessibility for the person who will assess and validate (or not) my project.

I've proceeded by adding a dotenv file in my project folder. In that file, I've created a variable called `MongoLink` and stored the connection string, replacing it in the `App.js` by `MongoLink`.

I've read that it's out of question to upload a dotenv file on GitHub so I added my dotenv file to the gitignore and the GitHub repository doesn't contain the dotenv file and so the connection string to MongoDB is nowhere to be found and the project can't be properly tested by anyone cloning the repository from Github.

I'm looking for an alternative way to secure the user/password information while maintaining the project ready to be cloned from its GitHub repository and tested without connection issues.

Comment: Whoever clones the repo provides their own MongoDB URI, to connect it to whatever DB they're using for testing. If you want to share access to your database instance with somebody specific, use another channel. You've already secured it correctly, by _not including it_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but does it work if I'm the creator of the database  on MongoDB ? I've read your post carefully but still need the precision, thanks !

Comment: @Elradsoldier send the connections string using an email

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "the database". There doesn't have to be only one, it doesn't matter who created it. I could clone your app and run it locally connected to a hosted instance on MongoDB Atlas, or a Docker container, or any other MongoDB I like; that's another benefit of parameterising the connection. It the DB needs loading with certain data or structure to be useful, provide scripts to do that as part of the code.

Comment: @jonrsharpeI think that I start to understand. Thanks for your answers It did help !